# How to extract html from certain position to another and add an attribute to it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, screen-scraping

I have this html :

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="img/karate/image1.jpg">Image 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="img/karate/image2.jpg">Image 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="img/boxing/image3.jpg">Image 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="img/karate/image4.jpg">Image 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="img/kungfu/image5.jpg">Image 5</a></li>
</ul>  

<button type="button">Red Color</button>
```

I want to :

1. Locate the word `karate` inside the list, then go back to the closest `<li>`
2. Mark it (the `<li>` tag) as the start position.
3. The end position would be its closing `</li>` tag.
4. Store the result in a string variable.
5. Add/append this attribute : `style="color:red;"` to the `<li>` tag.
6. All this by hitting the button, and using JavaScript.

The result : Image 1, Image 2 and Image 4 will be colored Red, Image 3 and Image 5 will be ignored.

I don't want to use JQuery or imported JS file like Cherrio because I want to understand every line !

I found things called web scraping, robots crawling... but i still can't understand it so any help would be much much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
"use strict";

let button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick() {
    let urls = document.querySelectorAll('a');

    for (let i = 0, max = urls.length; i < max; i++) {

        if (urls[i].href.indexOf('karate') !== -1) {
        
            if(urls[i].parentNode.tagName === 'LI') {
                urls[i].parentNode.className = 'makeRed';
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.makeRed, .makeRed a {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="img/karate/image1.jpg">Image 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="img/karate/image2.jpg">Image 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="img/boxing/image3.jpg">Image 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="img/karate/image4.jpg">Image 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="img/kungfu/image5.jpg">Image 5</a></li>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="button">Red Color</button>
```

Comment: If I want to do the same thing but this time it's similar phrases (string) inside a paragraph, for example ;
<p>
image/karate/image1.jpg,
image/karate/image2.jpg,
image/boxing/image3.jpg,
image/karate/image4.jpg,
image/kungfu/image5.jpg
</p>

Can i filter all lines (not including the comma at the end) where there is the word karate then append to each line some attribute ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the string image/ is the start position

Comment: yep you can, just put your items into array and make a loop search for your query

Comment: Ok thanks, but how to change this : if(urls[i].parentNode.tagName === 'LI') 
with a simple string like : images// . This time it's not a tag, it's just a text !

Comment: in such way you have no any html tag to use, and this complicates the task. So you have to get the string inside your <p> tag, then you have to parse you string and get an array with items. After you have to check each item with your keyword. When it will be done you have to generate a new html inside you <p> tag.